# How to convert a "apple"to "APPLE" with ascii code using flowchart

Tags: ascii, uppercase, converters

How to convert a "apple"to "APPLE" with ascii code using flowchart
i wrote it with python put how can i convert it to flowchart

```
sum=''
i=1
while i<=5:
    a1=input("plz input character : ")
    a=chr(ord(a1)-32)
    sum=sum+a
    i=i+1
print (sum)
```

Comment: Please share at least what you have tried

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't exactly know what you want but maybe try this?

https://code2flow.com/

I did it there and maybe this is what you are looking for?
[So something like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdDtY.png)